# How to add table in bookmarks using DOCX library C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, docx

I am creating one pdf file using docx library which needs a table to be inserted in perticular bookmark object. Currently I am able to replace a plain text in the bookmark object but unable to bind the table to bookmarks. Please help me to insert the table in bookmark objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer guys.. just need to add table to bookmark.

docxobj.Bookmark["bookmarkname"].inserttableafterSelf("tabname");

Thank u